# Query JSON-based API with user input with just javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, addeventlistener

I've been watching tutorials on using JSON data and JS, decided to work with an API and make a simple APP. I ran into a snag and I'm not sure what's causing the issue. The issue is around the way I'm using user input to modify the query string. When I make my endpoint something static and get rid of the 'movieSearch' function,like this:

```
const movies = [];
const endpoint = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=myAPIkey=batman';

fetch(endpoint)
 .then(blob => blob.json())
 .then(data => movies.push(...data.Search));
```

It works as desired, granted it's static.

My current code is:

```
  const movies = [];

  function movieSearch() {
    const replace = this.value;
    const endpoint = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=myAPIkey=' + replace;

    movies.length = 0;

    fetch(endpoint)
      .then(blob => blob.json())
      .then(data => movies.push(...data.Search));
  }

  function findMatches(wordToMatch, movies) {
    return movies.filter(film => {
      const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
      return film.Title.match(regex) || film.Year.match(regex)
    })
  }

  function displayMatches() {
    const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, movies);
    const html = matchArray.map(film => {
      const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
      const titleName = film.Title.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`)
      const yearName = film.Year.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`)
      return `
        <li>
          <span class="name">${titleName}, ${yearName}</span>
          <span class="population">${film.imdbID}</span>
        </li>
      `;
    }).join('');
    suggestions.innerHTML = html;
  }

  const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');
  const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

  searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', displayMatches);
  searchInput.addEventListener('change', displayMatches);
  searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', movieSearch);
```

The displayMatches function starts acting funny and sometimes returns the list items and other times doesn't. I can't figure out what's causing it. Whichever way I call my endpoint my movies array looks the same, so I'm thoroughly confused.

Any suggestions? Is there a better way to do this?

My HTML is fairly simple right now:

```
<form class="search-form">
 <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Movies">
 <ul class="suggestions">
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>test2</li>
 </ul>
</form>
```

Thanks!
(I'm trying to do this all in JS)

Edit:

An example of the JSON data when searching batman with the API:

```
{"Search":[{"Title":"Batman Begins","Year":"2005","imdbID":"tt0372784","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZmUwNGU2ZmItMmRiNC00MjhlLTg5YWUtODMyNzkxODYzMmZlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTIzOTk5ODM@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice","Year":"2016","imdbID":"tt2975590","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYThjYzcyYzItNTVjNy00NDk0LTgwMWQtYjMwNmNlNWJhMzMyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman","Year":"1989","imdbID":"tt0096895","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwNjAyODIyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDMwMDk2._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman Returns","Year":"1992","imdbID":"tt0103776","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BOGZmYzVkMmItM2NiOS00MDI3LWI4ZWQtMTg0YWZkODRkMmViXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODY0NzcxNw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman Forever","Year":"1995","imdbID":"tt0112462","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNWY3M2I0YzItNzA1ZS00MzE3LThlYTEtMTg2YjNiOTYzODQ1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman & Robin","Year":"1997","imdbID":"tt0118688","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMGQ5YTM1NmMtYmIxYy00N2VmLWJhZTYtN2EwYTY3MWFhOTczXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTA2NTI0MTY@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"The Lego Batman Movie","Year":"2017","imdbID":"tt4116284","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTcyNTEyOTY0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTAyNzU3MDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman: The Animated Series","Year":"1992–1995","imdbID":"tt0103359","Type":"series","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzI5OWU0MjYtMmMwZi00YTRiLTljMDAtODQ0ZGYxMDljN2E0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTA4NzY1MzY@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman: Under the Red Hood","Year":"2010","imdbID":"tt1569923","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTdlODI0YTYtNjk5ZS00YzZjLTllZjktYmYzNWM4NmI5MmMxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTA4NzY1MzY@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Batman: The Dark Knight Returns, Part 1","Year":"2012","imdbID":"tt2313197","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzIxMDkxNDM2M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5ODY1OQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"}],"totalResults":"344","Response":"True"}
```

Comment: Guess: because the movieSearch function is async the movies array might not always be updated in time. Try adding console.log(movies) in the displayMatches function.

Comment: @Abbe It's showing in the console but something strange is happening. When I open the array in the console it then completes the function by adding the list items to the UL.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but it seams to work for me: https://jsbin.com/zonipedada/edit?html,js,output I did some minor changes to make it work with an open API that I could use for testing.

Comment: Tip: for basic string search you can use 'string'.includes('value'): http://jsbin.com/boxepeloca/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Abbe That does seem to work. Could it have something to do with the way the API is returning the data? I edited my original comment with a sample return for the search batman.

Comment: I don't think so by just looking at it, would it be possible for you to post a jsbin or jsfiddle example? If the API key is supposed to go into a url variable it's going to be public anyway...

Comment: @Abbe Sure! Here it is: https://jsbin.com/jimaqateqo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues causing this behavior:

1. The `movieSearch` function is async and might not update the data in time.
2. The API sometimes return an error.

This solved by the code below, note that I moved everything into the fetch resolver making sure the search only executes when the API has responded.

Here is a JS Bin: https://jsbin.com/kicesivigu/1/edit?html,js,output

```
  function findMatches(wordToMatch, movies) {
    return movies.filter(film => {
      console.log(film.Title, wordToMatch);
      console.log(film.Title.toLowerCase().includes(wordToMatch));
      return film.Title.toLowerCase().includes(wordToMatch) || film.Year.toLowerCase().includes(wordToMatch);
    });
  }

  function displayMatches(movies, value) {
    const matchArray = findMatches(value.toLowerCase(), movies);
    const html = matchArray.map(film => {
      const regex = new RegExp(value, 'gi');
      const titleName = film.Title.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${value}</span>`);
      const yearName = film.Year.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${value}</span>`);
      return `
        <li>
          <span class="name">${titleName}, ${yearName}</span>
          <span class="population">${film.imdbID}</span>
        </li>
      `;
    }).join('');
    suggestions.innerHTML = html;
  }

  const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');
  const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');


searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  const endpoint = 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=63f88e02&s=' + searchInput.value;

  fetch(endpoint)
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('response from API');
      console.log(data);
      if (!data.Error) displayMatches(data.Search, searchInput.value);
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the problem and helped me understand how I should have wrote it. Thanks again!